# How to create dict object from a casted string?

Tags: python, csv, casting, directory

I'm trying to edit some dictionary values using Regular Expression and change them back into a dict object.

I am checking IP data using Shodan API, this returns a set of results, more than I need.

Shodan Ip

```
ipinfo {'city': None, 'region_code': None, 'os': None, 'tags': ['vpn'], 'ip': 771247238, 'isp': 'Host Universal Pty', 'area_code': None, 'dma_code': None, 'last_update': '2019-05-01T06:53:53.130508', 'country_code3': 'AUS', 'country_name': 'Australia', 'hostnames': [], 'postal_code': None, 'longitude': 143.2104, 'country_code': 'AU', 'ip_str': '45.248.76.134', 'latitude': -33.494, 'org': 'Host Universal Pty', 'data': [{'_shodan': {'id': 'bc2dc252-5b9d-4b3d-975f-0156860c8849', 'options': {}, 'ptr': True, 'module': 'https', 'crawler': '65e79faecee26516a8ed6f16c1142432f303fbdc'}, 'hash': 0, 'os': None, 'opts': {}, 'ip': 771247238, 'isp': 'Host Universal Pty', 'port': 443, 'hostnames': [], 'location': {'city': None, 'region_code': None, 'area_code': None, 'longitude': 143.2104, 'country_code3': 'AUS', 'country_name': 'Australia', 'postal_code': None, 'dma_code': None, 'country_code': 'AU', 'latitude': -33.494}, 'timestamp': '2019-05-01T06:53:53.130508', 'domains': [], 'org': 'Host Universal Pty', 'data': '', 'asn': 'AS136557', 'transport': 'tcp', 'ip_str': '45.248.76.134'}, {'_shodan': {'id': 'cdce36e7-588f-4377-8cc6-f9bedd426e6b', 'options': {}, 'ptr': True, 'module': 'https', 'crawler': '0636e1e6dd371760aeaf808ed839236e73a9e74d'}, 'hash': 0, 'os': None, 'opts': {}, 'ip': 771247238, 'isp': 'Host Universal Pty', 'port': 8443, 'hostnames': [], 'location': {'city': None, 'region_code': None, 'area_code': None, 'longitude': 143.2104, 'country_code3': 'AUS', 'country_name': 'Australia', 'postal_code': None, 'dma_code': None, 'country_code': 'AU', 'latitude': -33.494}, 'timestamp': '2019-04-26T18:31:18.138759', 'domains': [], 'org': 'Host Universal Pty', 'data': '', 'asn': 'AS136557', 'transport': 'tcp', 'ip_str': '45.248.76.134'}, {'_shodan': {'id': '27e5f5e0-662e-4621-b043-56d64d25f38d', 'options': {}, 'ptr': True, 'module': 'http', 'crawler': 'c9b639b99e5410a46f656e1508a68f1e6e5d6f99'}, 'hash': 0, 'os': None, 'opts': {}, 'ip': 771247238, 'isp': 'Host Universal Pty', 'http': {'robots_hash': None, 'redirects': [], 'securitytxt': None, 'title': None, 'sitemap_hash': None, 'robots': None, 'server': None, 'host': '45.248.76.134', 'html': None, 'location': '/', 'html_hash': None, 'sitemap': None, 'securitytxt_hash': None}, 'port': 8080, 'hostnames': [], 'location': {'city': None, 'region_code': None, 'area_code': None, 'longitude': 143.2104, 'country_code3': 'AUS', 'country_name': 'Australia', 'postal_code': None, 'dma_code': None, 'country_code': 'AU', 'latitude': -33.494}, 'timestamp': '2019-04-21T03:00:14.986062', 'domains': [], 'org': 'Host Universal Pty', 'data': '', 'asn': 'AS136557', 'transport': 'tcp', 'ip_str': '45.248.76.134'}, {'_shodan': {'id': 'bfbc3556-d00d-4512-8cb3-32ef6cae9964', 'options': {}, 'ptr': True, 'module': 'ike', 'crawler': '8cd926590a400feb4b683f8337a77287ddf3d2c7'}, 'hash': -451677272, 'os': None, 'tags': ['vpn'], 'opts': {'raw': '61713862726c6c3764627037343033792920252800000000000000240000000800000005'}, 'ip': 771247238, 'isp': 'Host Universal Pty', 'port': 500, 'isakmp': {'initiator_spi': '61713862726c6c37', 'responder_spi': '6462703734303379', 'msg_id': '00000000', 'next_payload': 41, 'exchange_type': 37, 'length': 36, 'version': '2.0', 'flags': {'encryption': False, 'authentication': False, 'commit': False}, 'aggressive': {'initiator_spi': 'a6517b6a97dca862', 'responder_spi': '1655d8123c9f2104', 'msg_id': 'd14144c6', 'next_payload': 11, 'exchange_type': 5, 'length': 40, 'version': '1.0', 'flags': {'encryption': False, 'authentication': False, 'commit': False}, 'vendor_ids': []}, 'vendor_ids': []}, 'hostnames': [], 'location': {'city': None, 'region_code': None, 'area_code': None, 'longitude': 143.2104, 'country_code3': 'AUS', 'country_name': 'Australia', 'postal_code': None, 'dma_code': None, 'country_code': 'AU', 'latitude': -33.494}, 'timestamp': '2019-04-13T11:18:42.166709', 'domains': [], 'org': 'Host Universal Pty', 'data': 'VPN (IKE)\n\nInitiator SPI: 61713862726c6c37\nResponder SPI: 6462703734303379\nNext Payload: RESERVED\nVersion: 2.0\nExchange Type: DOI Specific Use\nFlags:\n    Encryption:     False\n    Commit:         False\n    Authentication: False\nMessage ID: 00000000\nLength: 36', 'asn': 'AS136557', 'transport': 'udp', 'ip_str': '45.248.76.134'}], 'asn': 'AS136557', 'ports': [443, 8443, 8080, 500]}
```

I use Regular Expression to delete the data I don't need. This deletes anything from the fields' data' onwards.

```
osint_ip1 = re.sub("..'data':.*", "}", str(ipinfo))
```

Heres the problem... Since Showdan returns inconsistently depending on the IP, I need to use a Dirctwriter to write the corresponding values to there fields.

The problem with this is I have to cast ipinfo as a string to edit the data, and the string object canot be used in the CSV Directwriter.

How do I turn the string back into direction format?

OSINT(STRING)

```
rejoin : ["{'city': None", " 'region_code': None", " 'os': None", " 'tags': ['vpn']", " 'ip': 771247238", " 'isp': 'Host Universal Pty'", " 'area_code': None", " 'dma_code': None", " 'last_update': '2019-05-01T06:53:53.130508'", " 'country_code3': 'AUS'", " 'country_name': 'Australia'", " 'hostnames': []", " 'postal_code': None", " 'longitude': 143.2104", " 'country_code': 'AU'", " 'ip_str': '45.248.76.134'", " 'latitude': -33.494", " 'org': 'Host Universal Pty'}"]
```

Full code below

```
import csv
import os
import re
import time

import shodan
from shodan import Shodan


def OPSINT():
    for x in ip:
        print(x)
        try:
            ipinfo = api.host(x)
        except shodan.exception.APIError:
            ipinfo = None
            pass
        filename = 'C:\\ProgramData\\FDA\\output\\processed\\OSINT.csv'

        if ipinfo != None:
            osint_ip1 = re.sub("..'data':.*", "}", str(ipinfo))    
            osint_ip = osint_ip1.split(',')
            print("rejoin :", osint_ip)

           # print(osint_ip)
            print("ipinfo", ipinfo)

            with open("C:\\ProgramData\\FDA\\output\\processed\\OSINT.csv", 'a') as csvfile:
                fieldnames = ['city', 'region_code', 'os', 'tags', 'ip', 'isp', 'area_code', 'dma_code', 'last_update',
                              'country_code3', 'country_name', 'hostnames', 'postal_code', 'longitude', 'country_code',
                              'ip_str', 'latitude', 'org']
                writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
                fileEmpty = os.stat(filename).st_size == 0
                if fileEmpty:
                    writer.writeheader()
                else:
                    writer.writerows(osint_ip)

                csvfile.close()
```

Comment: The Shodan API is actually returning a `dict`, not a `set`, which is a different built-in Python container-type.

Comment: Our command-line interface also lets you convert a Shodan data file (ending in .json.gz) into CSV so you don't need to write any code. See: https://help.shodan.io/guides/how-to-convert-to-excel (use "csv" instead of "xlsx")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dict is a well-structured data type meant to be accessed and/or manipulated via keys. Manipulating a dict by converting it to a string and performing regex substitution is wholly unnecessary and error-prone.

Since you've already defined the exact keys you want as `fieldnames`, you can simply use `operator.itemgetter` to get the values of these keys from the dict `ipinfo`, and zip them with the key names to construct a new dict for `csv.DictWriter.writerow` to write from:

```
from operator import itemgetter
...
writer.writerow(dict(zip(fieldnames, itemgetter(*fieldnames)(ipinfo))))
```